# How to build only specific requirements

Tags: git, svn, cvs, build-script

we are looking to migrate from cvs to svn/git. But, before picking up one from svn/git I just a question in my mind i.e,

for example: developers have 10 requirements. Out of 10 requirements,developers worked on 6 requirements and requested for a build. So we r building all the 10 requirements. But, I am just looking to build only the 6 requirements by excluding remaining 4 requirements.

I came to know that,it is possible with git. Is there any alternative

is it possible? if so,how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily dedicate a branch in git which is monitored by a build scheduler (like the [Jenkins Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin)).
(You even can [auto-create a Jenkins job for any new feature branch](http://entagen.github.io/jenkins-build-per-branch/))

You can for example [`git cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) any commit you want to apply it on that branch and see if the build pass.

Comment: Is there any solution with SVN?

Comment: @user3781945 there should, considering Jenkins is well integrated with SVN. But git is easier to put in place.

Comment: can u explain me step-by-step procedure for doing this with cvs

Comment: @user3781945 CVS? That was way before my time... I wouldn't know how to use such an old tool. You could ask a new question for that.

Comment: can u explain me step-by-step procedure for doing this with svn.....if u had any supporting docs..just share with me

Comment: @user3781945 it would be best to ask a new question, with your exact setup (version of Jenkins and SVN) in order for me or others to detail the process: make a link to that old question as well.